# How to open a link in UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am having a chat application, which occasionally receives a link. On clicking that link, I can view the webpage in Safari, I would like to open that link in a UIWebview in my app instead.

I was going through [this article](http://www.alphansotech.com/blogs/how-to-use-web-view-in-ios-using-swift/), And its all good but it is giving in a hard coded link. I want to be able to open the link that user just clicked upon. whats the best way to achieve this?

Comment: show the code how the link gets actually handled in your application.

Comment: there is no code for that, I just click that link , and it opens in Safari automatically.

Comment: *"I am having a chat application, which occasionally receives a link."* Where is your code that handles the chat receiving? ***That*** is where you need to look.

Comment: @DonMag Thank you :)

Comment: I am getting normal string of data, I am putting it in a tableViewCell and displaying it on screen just like normal text. But because it has a link, the url text becomes blue and clickable like a hypelink. Clicking that it just opens that webpage in safari.

Comment: @Mayur - good, you are on the right path. *"I am putting it in a tableViewCell"* ... What object in your cell is getting the string? A label? A textfield? A textview? You need to determine what object is converting your string to allow a link to be tapped, and then "intercept" that tap to change its behavior.

Comment: It is a UItextView having a String of Data

Comment: @DonMag how do I intercept that tap and send the link to web view? I guess Prepare for segue will be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to first ask your `textView` to recognize urls

```
textView.text = "example www.google.com"
textView.isSelectable = true
textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.link
```

But then in delegate method `shouldInteractWithURL`, return false so that your URL is clickable but you will not jump to Safari.

```
extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith url: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
        print(url)
        //load url to YOUR web view here!
        return false
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set delegate!

```
textView.delegate = self
```

Comment: How to load the link to the webView ? like how to pass that selected link to the webView

Comment: @Mayur Call this `webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url))` on your webView.

Answer (score 0):

Jus setup a delegate to the UITextView and implement this function:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    // open URL in UIWebView
}
```

Remember to extend the UITextViewDelegate and set the delegate to self:

```
@IBOutlet var textview: UITextView!
class SomeVC: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textview.delegate = self
   }
}
```